# Running dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu but the files in "Other Locations" are all read-only

Tags: boot, windows, root, read-only

So pretty much, got around to partitioning off a segment of my NVME drive for Ubuntu for mining applications and stuff, but recently when I got the folding@home software it wouldn't detect my GPU and it seems like the main solution is to edit a text file in /var/lib/fahclient.

But this is through the "Other Locations" segment so not like in documents or desktop or anything that works fine and I can edit. For some reason, it's stuck as read-only.

I tried turning off fast boot and hibernate but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Linux works with a system of file permissions for security. Not everybody can edit any file on the system. Only a user that has administrator privileged can edit system files. The first user created after installing the system will have administrator privileges, i.e., is also system administrator. For other users on the system, this privilege must be granted by one of the existing system administrators.

Ubuntu does not work with a dedicated administrator account. Rather, it uses a system where the privileges of normal users temporarily can be elevated to these of an administror, using [sudo](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/sudo-beginners-guide/). Preceding a command with `sudo` allows the cmmand to proceed with administrator privileges, for example `sudo nano /var/lib/fahclient` would allow you to open the `fahclient` in the editor `nano`, change it and save it.